How to use ExcelMaxAllowedCellCount in pdftron javascrippt
I want to set a cell limit I am trying to use the ExcelMaxAllowedCellCount but it causes problems, try to use
WebViewer(...) .then(instance => { const opts = { ExcelMaxAllowedCellCount: 250000 }; const doc = await instance.Core.createDocument(file, { officeOptions : { officeToPDFOptions: opts }}); instance.UI.loadDocument('https://myserver.com/myfile.xslx', { filename: 'myfile.xslx' }); });
but I still have error, greetings
